# Missing Keyword WITHIN Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I'm adding a @Formula in my model/entity class in order to make a request for each element.

```
@Formula("(select (LISTAGG(ver.ACC_DESC_ES, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ACC_ID)) from TSEN_ACCIONES_BIB acc, VSEN_ELC_REVISION ver where ELC_ID = acc.ACC_ELC_ID and acc.ACC_ACTIVA='S')")
```

The problem is that Hibernate takes WITHIN as a table column and it generates a query without it.

```
select
        count(*)
    from
        TSEN_ACCIONES_BIB acc
    where
        revisionit0_.ELC_ID = acc.ACC_ELC_ID
        and acc.ACC_ACTIVA='N'
        and (
            acc.ACC_RESALTAR='S'
            or acc.ACC_RESALTAR='R'
        )) as formula3_0_,
    (select
        LISTAGG(revisionit0_.ACC_DESC,
        ', ') revisionit0_.WITHIN
    GROUP (ORDER BY
        revisionit0_.ACC_ID)
    from
        TSEN_ACCIONES_BIB acc
    where
        revisionit0_.ELC_ID = acc.ACC_ELC_ID
        and acc.ACC_ACTIVA='S') as formula4_0_,
```

As you can see, WITHIN GROUP is changed to revisionit0_.WITHIN
GROUP.

How can I deal with it?
Thanks

Comment: You probably have to add `WITHIN` to the list of keywords in the dialect.

Answer (score 0):

This is not hibernate issue but a problem with your query.
Inner query should be named or aliased and you are missing a name so WITHIN is construed as name.

Correct line will be

```
@Formula("(select (LISTAGG(ver.ACC_DESC_ES, ', ') TEMPCOLNAME WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ACC_ID)) from TSEN_ACCIONES_BIB acc, VSEN_ELC_REVISION ver where ELC_ID = acc.ACC_ELC_ID and acc.ACC_ACTIVA='S')")
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved by myself changing the WITHIN with \00WITHIN.

Maybe @DhruvJoshi answer will work too.

```
 @Formula("(select (LISTAGG(ver.ACC_DESC_ES, ', ') \00WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ACC_ID)) from TSEN_ACCIONES_BIB acc, VSEN_ELC_REVISION ver where ELC_ID = acc.ACC_ELC_ID and acc.ACC_ACTIVA='S')")
```